# Using Owin with IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, owin

i have just started learning owin and would like to give it a try, but i have few confusions regarding owin. Hope i can get help here.
I a planning to use owin in my MVC 5 application and host it using IIS. Following are my questions regarding this approach.

1. Will IIS still use HttpModules if i am using owin middlewares?
2. Is it mandatory to handle the IIS events in my owin middleware using   app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate) ?
3. If i am handling events in my owin middleware, will the event handler in httpmodule gets called?
4. If i am not able to host my MVC 5 application without IIS than what will be the use of using Owin in my application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yu probably should save some energy on OWIN as ASP.NET Core does not use it. Jump to ASP.NET MVP Core, at http://dot.net check it out, but it would be more mature only later this year with the next release of Visual Studio.

Comment: You mean to say ASP.net core doesnot use owin ?

Comment: You can get right answer from http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline.

1.IIS still use HttpModules.

2.The stage markers are used to make other stage to run earlier!=> you can tell httpmodules process PipelineStage.Authenticate state before OWIN continue process others.

3. Yes